# About C++ STL list class method erase()

Tags: c++, list, stl

The documentation of `list::erase()` says, "call destructor before", what does this mean? If I want to `erase(it)` a item and then `push_back(*it)` the item again, will that be illegal since it was destructed already?

Comment: Are you sure that `std::list` is the right container for your use case?  There are very few use cases where a linked list offers ideal performance characteristics.

Comment: @James McNellis- Based on the above use case it seems like the OP is trying to move elements around in the list.  That would be a pretty good use case, since all other sequences take O(n) to do it.

Comment: @templatetypedef:  Perhaps.  I'd still be very hesitant to recommend `std::list` without knowing exactly how it is being used.  The size of each element, the cost of copying each element, the number of elements, and the relative frequency of splicing vs. iteration are all important criteria, and we don't know any of those things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this will result in undefined behavior.  Once you `erase` a list iterator you *invalidate* the iterator, meaning that the object it references is no longer guaranteed to be valid.  This means that if you then try to use the iterator in any context, including trying to dereference the value to add it to the list again, it will result in undefined behavior, which could crash the program, overwrite important memory, or do nothing.

If you want to move an element of a list to the back, consider using the list's `splice` method:

```
myList.splice(myList.end(), myList, it);
```

This moves the element to the end without making a copy.

Comment: Won't that splice a whole lot more than just that single element? Checked the documentation. You're correct, that will do exactly the right thing.

Comment: +1; Also a method that I'd missed. See also the version which does the same with a range of iterators.

Answer (score 2):

The element in the container is destroyed when it is removed from the container.  If you want to keep the object after you remove it from the container, you need to make a copy of it and use the copy instead.

Your proposed code:

```
v.erase(it);
v.push_back(*it);
```

is invalid because `it` is invalidated after the erasure.  You cannot use an iterator after it has been invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing erase and iterators can be a very tricky business. The validity of various iterators after you've done an erase can vary form container to container. The thing you should do if you want to do an `erase` and a `push_back` is to save a copy of what's in `*it` first, then using the copy when you do a `push_back`.

Answer (score 0):

The item is erased by destroying it and then removing the reference to it from the list.  If you want to retain the item then you need to take a copy of it before calling erase.  All of this suggests that perhaps std::list is not the correct container for your needs.